# Cannot export an API key to .zshrc including special characters

Tags: node.js, api, zsh

I want to store an API key in my .zshrc file so I can access it through process.env in Node.js.

Right now, this will work:

`export MY_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY="h2hj"`,

whereas this will not:

`export MY_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY="h2.hj"`.

This is the error I am seeing when trying to get my terminal up to date: `source ~/.zshrc
/Users/username/.zshrc:export:103: not valid in this context: h2.hj`

Is there a way to allow special characters like this? Thanks in advance for any advice or help!

Comment: What error are you seeing? Seems to me that that should work. It certainly works in bash anyway.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reading. I'll include the error in the main post, but here it is: `source ~/.zshrc
/Users/username/.zshrc:export:103: not valid in this context: h2.hj`

Comment: Downloaded zsh and put that export statement in an otherwise empty zshrc. It runs happily and sets the value. Is that line 103 of the zshrc? Is there anything else that that interacts with that variable in your zshrc?

Comment: The key is on that line, I just tried with h2.hj (it's not my actual key :p) and it still didn't work, same error. I have other keys that work just fine, it just really hates dots.
I've gotten around the problem for now by creating a config.js file containing the key that I'm setting to be ignored in git. It's not ideal though, I'd still love to work this out!

Comment: Is the value inserted directly from a string or does it come from a command: `export ASDF=$(do shtuff)`? Are there any spaces around the `=`?

Comment: As long as it's wrapped in double quotes it should work.

Comment: Oh wow. Yup. I had a space after the equals, looks like that was it! Thank you so much for the help, I feel dumb but happy.

Shouuld I delete this post? Or is this useful..? :/

Comment: It happens. Posted an answer in case someone stumbles upon this with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Shells are very picky about spaces. It's likely that you either have spaces where you shouldn't:

```
export MY_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY = "h2.hj"
```

or you're using a value without quotes that contains spaces:

```
export MY_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY=$(echo "hello world")
```

In the first example, you can fix the issue by removing the spaces around the `=` and in the second example can be fixed by using quotes:

```
export MY_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY="$(echo 'hello world')"
```